# Is there a better way to let libraries'(for example ring, compojure) keywords known to the emacs autocomplete plugin?

Tags: emacs, clojure, autocomplete

I am using emacs autocomplete plugin, actually i am using Emacs Live(https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) which in turn uses autocomplete.
Autocomplete does work, but it only know the keywords list in the /dict/xxx files.
When i add libs to current project using lein (for example ring, compojure), it doesn't work at all.
Do i have to list all keywords in the libs to /dict directory to make autocomplete know them?
Or is there a way to let autocomplete know the keywords each time i add a new lib using lein(Just like what happens in Java IDE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Barrett's answer gets you almost there.

Install nrepl and ac-nrepl from melpa, then put this in your init:

```
(require 'nrepl)
(require 'ac-nrepl)

(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
  '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'nrepl-mode))
```

And use `M-x nrepl-jack-in` to hook your emacs session to your clojure project with auto complete and doc hints.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs live still uses Swank to talk to Clojure, right? You could try using [nrepl](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el) as an alternative to Swank, which provides autocompletion of java libraries.

You're right that adding additional sources to Autocomplete is a bit involved. There's a variable called `ac-sources` which is what you customise to add completion sources. There's info on the built-in ones [here](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Builtin_Sources).

Here's what I have in my init.el:

```
(set-default 'ac-sources
             '(ac-source-abbrev
               ac-source-dictionary
               ac-source-yasnippet
               ac-source-words-in-buffer
               ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers
               ac-source-semantic))
```

This should make autocomplete a bit more useful for you.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Did you get it work? If you try to add a new lib using lein, what would you do to make it a source of autocompletion. Your init.el is the almost the same as mine.